# iperf multicast server cannot start - "bind failed: Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: networking, multicast, iperf

I've seen this question asked on here but the user was using Windows XP and Windows 7, and none of the answers I saw worked for me. I'm trying to set up a multicast server on Windows 10, and I downloaded iperf 2.0.9 64-bit directly from iperf.fr. When I attempt to start a multicast server I run the following command and get back the error:

```
Command: iperf -s -u -B 224.0.0.5 -i 10
Output: bind failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

It doesn't matter what IP address I set it to, the error is always there. The only exception is if I bind it to the client's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a much newer version of iperf 2, e.g. [2.1.9-rc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/files/iperf-2.1.9-rc-win.exe/download)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).